# Android: Button doesn't respond suddenly

Tags: android, database, button, onclicklistener

My Button doesn't respont suddenly... Yesterday it worked very well and when I came back to the computer it doesn't work anymore...

When I click on the Button cmd_forward nothing happens... No logcat no reaction at the device...

Part of Oncreate:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.question);
    _id = getIntent().getIntExtra("ID", 1);
    Log.v("ID:", ""+_id);
    filldata();


    Button cmd_forward = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cmd_forward);
    cmd_forward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {    
            if(_id == 9){
                Log.v("TRUE", "TRUE");
                int min = 1;
                int max = 107;

                Random r = new Random();
                int random = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;

                c = db.rawQuery("SELECT question, answer FROM tbl_questions"+
                        " where _id =='"+random+"'", null);

                if (c != null ) {
                    if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
                              question = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("question"));
                              answer = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("answer"));                   
                              TextView tv_question = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_question);                      

                              tv_question.setText(question);
                    }
               }
            } else {


            if(c.moveToNext()){
              question = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("question"));
              answer = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("answer"));                   

              TextView tv_question = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_question);                      

              tv_question.setText(question);
            }
            }
        }
    });
```

filldata():

```
    public void filldata(){

    db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("/data/data/spicysoftware.abugrundwissen/databases/questions", null,
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

    if(_id == 9){

        int min = 1;
        int max = 107;

        Random r = new Random();
        _id= r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;

        c = db.rawQuery("SELECT question, answer, favourite FROM tbl_questions"+
                " where _id =='"+_id+"'", null);

        if (c != null ) {
            if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
                      question = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("question"));
                      answer = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("answer"));        
                      favourite = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("favourite"));
                      TextView tv_question = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_question);                      

                          tv_question.setText(question);


            }
       }

    } else {
    c = db.rawQuery("SELECT question, answer, favourite FROM tbl_questions"+
            " where rubrik =='"+_id+"'", null);

    if (c != null ) {
        if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
                  question = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("question"));
                  answer = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("answer"));    
                  favourite = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("favourite"));
                  TextView tv_question = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_question);                      

                      tv_question.setText(question);

        }
   }

}

}
```

LogCat:

```
01-18 07:19:07.015: D/dalvikvm(617): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 68K, 5% free 6554K/6855K, paused 29ms, total 30ms
01-18 07:19:07.095: D/dalvikvm(617): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 6% free 6810K/7175K, paused 30ms, total 31ms
01-18 07:19:07.095: I/dalvikvm-heap(617): Grow heap (frag case) to 6.946MB for 262160-byte allocation
01-18 07:19:07.175: D/dalvikvm(617): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 6% free 7066K/7495K, paused 30ms, total 30ms
01-18 07:19:07.185: V/ID:(617): 9
01-18 07:19:10.855: I/Choreographer(617): Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: `The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.` means need to use AsyncTask or thread for making database operation in background thread instead of on main ui thread

Comment: Hmm.. Feels like black magic involved here. But seriously, try to debug your application to see where the problem lays. Do you really think that anyone will be able to find the bug based on a code snippet?

Comment: Have you tried debugging to see if `_id` equals 9?

Comment: _id is 9 take a look to the loccat. Database would be created at the first time of starting the app... so not on this activity.

Comment: Problem has been solved, check out my answer! Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, that i gave "_id" in filldata(); another value. So it wasn't 9!